# How to choose compatible dependency while resolving issue of duplicate dependency?

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, java-11

I am working on updating my jdk from java8 to java11. Meanwhile I am getting duplicate dependency warnings. I know the method of how to resolve a dependency using exclusion but not getting which dependency I should keep. Basically, I am not unable to find out which dependency is compatible with my Project. I m using Spring5.1.4.RELEASE and Maven 2.5

1. I solve some dependencies warnings by checking which one contains every class of another one. Basically the one which is subset I removed that.
2. Some by checking the publish year difference.

These things are helping ,but I am not sure is it correct or not.

This is the list of dependencies which are conflicting. 
Help me to decide which one to choose.

1. `spring-jcl-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar` OR `commons-logging-1.2.jar`
2. `taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar` OR `jstl-1.2.jar`
3. `jaxb-impl-2.3.1.jar` OR `jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar`
4. `jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar` OR `jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar`
5. `jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar` OR `jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar`
6. `annotations-2.0.1.jar` OR `jcip-annotations-1.0.jar`

Comment: You should post the pom.xml so we can see how you are importing them with the right setup.

Comment: If possible you should use a more recent maven version.